# Connect Power BI to Spark thrift

Tags: apache-spark, powerbi

I am trying to configure spark and connect to power bi.

I add the following properties to the hive-site.xml

```
<property>
   <name>hive.server2.transport.mode</name>
   <value>http</value>
</property>

<property>
   <name>hive.server2.thrift.http.port</name>
   <value>9999</value>
</property>

<property>
   <name>hive.server2.http.endpoint</name>
   <value>cliservice</value>
</property>

<property>
   <name>hive.server2.thrift.http.path</name>
   <value>cliservice</value>
</property>
```

It works well for beeline

```
!connect jdbc:hive2://34.66.189.xxx:9999
```

However, it throws errors when connecting to PowerBI
[image]

I keep my [user name] and [password] empty
[image]

And it throws an error

[image]

Many Thanks if anyone can give a helping hand.
Should I keep the username and password empty?

Comment: The error is explicitly talking about SSL. Have you tried with `https://...` instead of `http://...`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to enter an username AND password. Since you didn't configure that in your hive settings, it doesn't matter what you input.

The reason its required is because the Thriftserver tries to access the username and password you entered which is sent as an array. However, if you don't input an username and password, the array is empty and access the array's index at 0 and 1 will throw an ArraysOutOfBoundsException.